# Future of dojo mobile

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

I am working on enterprise-level business applications, and now is the time to start thinking about the non-desktop experience.
We have a common component code-base that is using dojo, and are trying to get as much code re-use as possible.

I am really struggling to determine if I should re-use the same code base, or have separate code bases for desktop and mobile.

A big factor in my decision making is the viabliity of dojox/mobile.
It seems pretty cool, and uses the dojo infrastructure which is a huge win, but the fact that it is in dojox scares me a little.

Some questions:

- Is dojox/mobile something that can be relied on long term?
- Is it a smart idea to try to swap out dijit components for dojox/mobile components depending on what has.js can tell me?
- Will dojox/mobile be a part of dojo2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on dojox/mobile. DojoX will indeed disappear from the Dojo Toolkit in 2.0, but most matured (and probably maintained) modules will be pushed to the dijit/dojo library. I quote the reference guide:

> In the future (Dojo 2.0), the DojoX package and namespace will
>   removed. Sub-Packages and modules will be either integrated into the
>   Dojo Core, Dijit or separated as their own stand-alone package. For
>   the 1.X code stream though, in order to ensure backwards
>   compatibility, all these packages are contained within the dojox
>   namespace and package.

If we look at the explanation of **Mature**, we can read the following:

> This package or module is considered mature and is being actively
>   developed and maintained by committers within the Dojo Toolkit. It is
>   expected that it will persist into the foreseeable future.

[Source](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/)

And if you look at the link above, you will notice that `dojox/mobile` is categorized as mature.

---

Another reason you can rely on it is that IBM (which can be considered a pretty big company and committer to the Dojo toolkit) also relies on `dojox/mobile` for their mobile product called IBM Worklight. If they rely on it, then there's no reason you couldn't.

---

I don't think it will be easy to start from the same code base and swap out `dijits` for `dojox/mobile` components. Usually mobile app development requires an entire different strategy than web applications. You will probably have to split certain things into multiple views and some dijits may not have a mobile alternative.

You can probably re-use most of your utilities and business logic, but I think you will have to start from scratch again if you want to write your view(s). But I'm not really an advanced mobile developer.

Answer (score 2):

I would add that in Dojo 2.0 the plan is to converge as much as possible the desktop (dijit) and the mobile (dojox/mobile) widgets which should help in your use-case. See: http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-contributors/2013-June/029041.html

Comment: See also: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ee4XL4TtTxojtkgRRetm4uIMAmiazH1CrA5Q6FKTlrM/edit?authkey=CMWJgtwE